# modify file content

Tags: bash, file-io, ssh, lighttpd, file-permissions

I'm installing a lighttpd server on a remote machine using a bash script. After installation, I need to configure the port for the server. The system says I don't have permission to modify the file /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf even though I do

```
sudo echo "server.bind=2000" >> /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

How shall I modify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing is running `echo` as root, then trying to append its output to the config file as the normal user.

What you want is `sudo sh -c 'echo "server.bind=2000" >> /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the file permission using `chmod`

```
$ sudo chmod a+x /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

Comment: Uhm... who needs to EXECUTE that config file?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the right to change the file `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` check the man page of `lighthttpd`. If you can start it with a different config file, then create a config file somewhere and start `lighthttpd` with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the bit on the right of >> is not run under sudo.  Either use sudo -i to bring up a root shell a superuser and run the command, or just use an editor as mentioned before.